# four players named A, B C and D and dealt 13 card hands, count possibilities for everyone.

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations

> Four players $A, B, C$ and $D$ are dealt $13$ card hand to each player. How many possibilities are there overall for what hands everyone will get assuming that it matters which player gets what hand, but the order within the hand does not matter.

So because it matters which player gets which hand, then this is equivalent to shuffling the $52$ cards and dealing four $13$ card piles and then randomly assigning each pile to every player. (it matters who gets a $13$ card pile). So the answer is
$$\frac{52!}{13!\cdot13!\cdot13!\cdot13!}$$

Note that if it did not matter which player get each pile, then we have to adjust for over-counting by $4!$.

$$\frac{52!}{13!\cdot13!\cdot13!\cdot13!\cdot4!}$$

Is this correct?  The thing I want to clear up is the language of these problems.  The problem states that "it matters which player gets which hand, but not the order within a hand."

This means that the order in which the $13$ cards does not matter, (it is just a set of $13$), but the $13$ card hand matters to who it is dealt.  So we don't adjust for over-counting. This means that pile $1$ is assigned to player $A$, this is a different outcome if pile $1$ was given to $B$, etc.

How would I go about solving the total possibilities if the order WITHIN each pile matters?

Comment: Your first answer is correct. If order within each pile matters then just multiply by $4! $.

Comment: Your first answer is correct.  If the order within each hand mattered, the answer would simply be $52!$.  Shuffle the deck.  Assign the first $13$ cards to player $A$ in the order that they appear, the next $13$ cards to player $B$ in the order they appear, the following $13$ cards to player $C$ in the order they appear, and the final $13$ cards to player $D$ in the order they appear.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig This is a fairly complete answer rather than a comment. Please would you consider posting as an answer.